# Very basic python file creater issue

Tags: python

I want this program to take whatever is input in myFile, and create the positive integer n times. Every file i test, it throws an error saying it does not exist. What is the issue here? Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
def createFile(myFile,n):
    #this must be a positive integer
    if n < 0:
        return "Enter a positive integer."
    opener = open(fileName,"w")
    for x in range(n):
        opener.write(str(random.randint(-1000,1000) + "\n"))
    opener.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

The input argument is called myFile, but later in the open call you are using filename.

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes you should fix...

- **Line 5:** should give you an error, because the variable `fileName` doesn't exist - replace it with `myFile`, the variable your function takes as an argument.
- **Line 7:** will give you an error because you are adding the integer and the string *inside* the `str` call: use str on the integer first, and then add the newline string.

With these two mistakes fixed (and random imported), your code should be working fine. If you are still receiving errors, your system might be preventing the program from creating the file.